# How to delete corrupted directory on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory, rm

I have a machine which has a directory that seems corrupt. The output of `ls -lah` is something like:

```
???????????  ? ?        ?           ?            ? dir_name
```

This used to be a valid directory in a CentOS 7 VM on SSD. I don't know what happened but now I just want to delete it, but that does not seem possible:

```
$sudo rm -rf dir_name 
rm: cannot remove ‘dir_name’: Is a directory
```

And `stat` can't read it either:

```
stat dir_name
stat: cannot stat ‘dir_name’: No such device
```

What's the simplest way to have this directory safely deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot delete corrupted dirs.

You must `umount` the filesystem and perform a `fsck`

as per  `man 8 fsck`

> fsck - check and repair a Linux filesystem

Answer (score 2):

Although the generic answer was given, just want to point out that in my particular case, this directory was also used as an SMB (cifs) mount point, which I could see with the `mount` command. So the solution was to simply do:

```
sudo umount /home/user/dir_name
```

And then the directory looked normal again and I was able to delete it as usual.